# Is 1000 Base SX fiber multimode (850nm) backwards compatible with 100 Base Sx fiber multimode (850nm)?

Tags: networking, fiber, gigabit-ethernet

Is 1000 Base SX fiber multimode (850nm) interface backwards compatible with 100 Base Sx fiber multimode (850nm) interface?

Comment: This question is too vague to answer as asked. It's not even clear what you mean by "interface".

Answer (score 1):

No - 1000BaseSX has no negotiation capability.  A 100M fiber interface is incompatible.

Comment: Either way, it's a question of whether you can connect a 1000BaseSX interface to a 100M fiber interface.

Comment: The question is vague, but the term 'interface' tends to connote a connection on a host of some sort.  I'll add to this the fact that I have yet to see a fiber cable labeled either 100- or 1000- baseSX, much less mentioning the wavelength of light, but I have seen plenty of host interfaces that have both of these specified.  As to the negotiation - that would be implicit in connecting two interfaces of different speeds.  I had assumed the question was whether the fiber interface could negotiate down to 100M much as a 100/1000 copper interface might.

Comment: Re-read your own link.  That interface has both an SFP and an RJ-45.  You choose which one you want to use with the media-type command.  The speed command only applies to the RJ45 interface (10/100/1000).  There are SFP optics that can support 100SX and there are SFP optics that support 1000SX.  Connect the two and you do not get a link.

Comment: I'm not missing any point.  The product in the link you just supplied takes -two- optics to achieve conversion between 100SX and 1000SX - one 100, one 1000.  -It's a conversion box-.  You need conversion boxes because these two link types are not compatible...which was the original question.